# Why my tkinter title bar is not changing?

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't understand why the title bar is not changing:

```py
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

    class Face_Recognization_System:
        def _init_(self, root):
            self.root = root
            self.root.title("Simple Prog")
            self.root.geometry("1530x790+0+0")
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    
        root = Tk()
        obj = Face_Recognization_System()
    
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors the first is in the syntax of  Initialization it's

```
__init__    Not   _init_
```

Second you should enter the root as an input.

And finally you change it up  a little to separate the initialization from the other method .

```
from tkinter import* 
from tkinter import ttk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Face_Recognization_System:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
    def change(self):
        self.root.title("Simple Prog")
        self.root.geometry("1530x790+0+0")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    obj = Face_Recognization_System(root)
    obj.change()

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass your root in parameter of the function. This should be better

```
obj = Face_Recognization_System(root)
```

Comment: when I am adding root the error is showingTypeError: Face_Recognization_System() takes no arguments

Comment: `def __init__(self, root) :` instead of `def init(self, root) :`

Comment: def _init_(self, root):  is already added

Comment: with two `_` on each side

Comment: Nice ! I'm happy that my answer helped you ! Can you validate my answer to close your question please

Comment: sure but I don't know how to close question

Comment: You should hava a "check" icone under the score of the answer ( [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) )

Comment: Got it ......Done :)